# How to enable hidden Arabic keyboard without rooting?

Tags: keyboard, samsung-galaxy-s-3

I've **Samsung Galaxy S3** device.
(Model-Number: **SPH-L710**)
(Android-Version: **4.1.1**)

I want to enable the hidden Arabic keyboard without rooting, or an extra keyboard application.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:
- Settings > Language and input > Keyboards and input methods

Tab Samsung keyboard settings, then select Input languages, you will get a list of Downloaded and Available (to download) languages.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [GO SMS Pro](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jb.gosms) and [Arabic for Go Keyboard](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jb.gokeyboard.langpack.ar&hl=en).

Comment: Thank you. But I told you I don't want any extra application I need to enable it on the system. Because the system's keyboard support the gesture typing.

Comment: @user1843769 Does your phone support Arabic in the first place? I know languages depend on the ROM. There are different ROMs for different regions or countries (Europe, Asia, etc). So if your ROM does not support Arabic by default, you won't have Arabic. So I think an external keyboard application is your best option. Or if you really want Arabic keyboard with your current ROM, I think you might need to root, and install it there manually (I don't know about installing keyboards).